# Change Color of Commands in Console2

Tags: windows-7, console2

I want to change the color of the actual command prompt, and not the color of the rest of console.

For example:

```
C:\Users\home> dir  (THIS LINE IS BRIGHT YELLOW)
30/09/2011  07:18 PM    <DIR>          .          (REST OF LINES ARE WHITE)
30/09/2011  07:18 PM    <DIR>          ..
```

The reason for this is when I execute commands that produce a lot of output and I wish to find previous commands.  However, since they are usually all the same color, its difficult to spot actual "prompts".

Comment: Are you using vanilla console2 or with cygwin?

Answer (score 3):

You satisfied with the yellow color in the prompt only?

[image: ANSI X3.64 in prompt]

Screenshot was taken from my own Console Emulator ([ConEmu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/)), sorry for self-promoton ;)

Link to [ColorPrompt.cmd](http://conemu-maximus5.googlecode.com/svn/files/Temp/ColorPrompt.cmd).

If you want repeat this trick in Console2, you owe to use [AnsiCon](http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon/) after (or before) changing prompt.

```
ansicon.exe -p
```

The idea is to use ANSI x3.64 sequences to change console output colors.

Comment: Where you actually want to put that URL i can't find out you should have to use format buttons until you don't know hoe to proper format manually. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do that with console2, (help file doesn't seem to work for me) You can try using a different shell such as [cygwins](http://www.cygwin.com/) bash. For me, the default bash terminal comes with the prompt already highlighted in a separate color (green). It works fine under console2 as well.

```
cd [YOUR CYGWIN INSTALL]
bash --login -i
```